# Is it possible to automatically suspend users in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There's an application that uses devise and I would like to add the possibility to automatically suspend an account (14 days trial). I was looking for something to expire a devise user but all I found was this: https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension which doesn't really help me.

Does anyone know a way to automatically suspend a user account after certain time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for expiration in a before_action

```
class ApplicationController << ActionController::Base

  before_action :check_expiration

  def check_expiration
    if current_user && current_user.status == 'trial' 
      if Date.today - current_user.created_at.to_date > 14
        flash[:error] = "Your trial has expired!"
        sign_out current_user
        redirect_to :new_session_path
      end
    end
  end

end
```